# How to update array in php?

Tags: php

I want to update the following array:

```
$old_array = array('c' => array( "a" => "1", "b" => "2"))
```

By adding the following array to it:

```
$new_array = array('cc' => array( "a" => "1", "b" => "2"))
```

My expected output is:

```
$update_array = array('c' => array( "a" => "1", "b" => "2"), 'cc' => array( "a" => "1", "b" => "2"))
```

How would I go about achieving this? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Just use `array_merge();` like `$update_array = array_merge($old_array, $new_array);`

Comment: as @executable said, check http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

Comment: Thanks guys, work it.

Comment: Use array_push()

Comment: Can you please modify your question & remove - 'I going to update array with new array'. Actually you need a merge, but this sentence conveys wring message. :-) 
Happy coding!

Comment: I'm sorry!now it's ok,

Comment: Thanks for giving more clarity. Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to merge the array using the function `array_merge()`

More information about the function [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php).

```
$old_array = array('c' => array( "a" => "1", "b" => "2")); 
$new_array = array('cc' => array( "a" => "1", "b" => "2"));

// merge arrays
$merged_array = array_merge($old_array, $new_array);
```

Comment: Nice! If it solved your issue, please consider upvoting / accepting the answer. It will help other people in the future. (You can accept an answer 15 minutes after the question being asked)

Comment: Done! Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You can use array_merge

```
$old_array = array('c' => array( "a" => "1", "b" => "2"));
$new_array = array('cc' => array( "a" => "1", "b" => "2"));

$result = array_merge($old_array, $new_array);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with array_merge() :

```
$old_array = array('c' => array( "a" => "1", "b" => "2")) ;
$new_array = array('cc' => array( "a" => "1", "b" => "2"));
$update_array = array_merge($old_array, $new_array);
```

**Output:**

```
array:2 [▼
  "c" => array:2 [▼
    "a" => "1"
    "b" => "2"
  ]
  "cc" => array:2 [▼
    "a" => "1"
    "b" => "2"
  ]
]
```